# Proving a file exists? Also how to stop your program freezing when scapeing websites

Tags: c#, file, download, html-agility-pack, freeze

Hey I am beginning to learn both C# and HtmlAgilityPack, so far I am working on a little test project. One issue that I am having is checking if a file already exists as to not download it twice.

Another issue is that while scraping the website/downloading the image my whole program will freeze for a period of time before becoming functional again, is there a way around this?

```
if (!File.Exists(@"Res\" + pokeName + ".jpg"))
        {
            var item = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='image']//img")[0];
            if (doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='image']//img") != null)
            {
                getImage(item.GetAttributeValue("src", ""));
                pictureBox1.Load(@"Res\" + pokeName + ".jpg");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            pictureBox1.Load(@"Res\" + pokeName + ".jpg");
        }
```

and

public void getImage(string url)
        {

```
        string imageUrl = @""+ url;
        string saveLocation = @"Res\"+ pokeName + ".jpg";

        byte[] imageBytes;
        HttpWebRequest imageRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imageUrl);
        WebResponse imageResponse = imageRequest.GetResponse();

        Stream responseStream = imageResponse.GetResponseStream();

        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(responseStream ))
        {
            imageBytes = br.ReadBytes(500000);
            br.Close();
        }
        responseStream.Close();
        imageResponse.Close();

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveLocation, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
        try
        {
            bw.Write(imageBytes);
        }
        finally
        {
            fs.Close();
            bw.Close();
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: It's better to ask one question per SO Question.

Comment: Is there something about `File.Exists` that isn't working?

Comment: Look into `BackgroundWorker` to have the work of downloading done in the background while still being able to provide progress to the UI.

Comment: @Peter Ritchie , Thanks ill keep that in mind. I am not sure if I am using it correctly, as for the background worker, I looked into it a little but I dont really understand. Would you know any good tutorial or resource I could use to help me understand?

Comment: Instead of your getImage method you could simply use [WebClient.DownloadFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/ez801hhe.aspx) or the async variant of that method to avoid your UI freezing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is probably freezing because you have long running items on the UI thread.

You will probably want to look at either using the background worker as previously mentioned, or (if you are using .Net 4.5) the new async/await system

GetStreamAsync is pretty much perfect for this situation, when you have a potential long wait or lots of items to work with instead of getting them iteratively
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/hh551738.aspx

Also as a side note, the code you put if I had 3 images {1.jpg, 2.jpg, foo/1.jpg} you wouldn't get the third because the name matched the first image, there are also a lot more image extensions than jpeg/jpg :)

Comment: Thanks, It is all a lot clearer now everything is working perfectly.